# CSS width subtraction

Tags: css

How to subtract width in CSS?

For example:

```
width = 100% - 10px
```

I'm not talking about padding or margin.

Comment: @Kyle, sorry but 10px is not 10%.

Comment: @Kyle - won't work.  10% != 10px unless the container is 100px.

Comment: Aha, I see that.. Sorry, misread :)

Comment: I know you specifically asked about width subtraction, but depending on what you are trying to achieve, if you use `box-sizing: border-box` to make padding be a part of (instead of in addition to) the width, you could use `width: 100%` with `padding: 0 10px`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Now with [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) the solution will be :

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

`Calc` can be use with Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division.

Additional note :

> Note: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.
>   The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a
>   percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while
>   the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus
>   sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a
>   length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage. The * and /
>   operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is
>   allowed, and recommended.

Comment: what is browser compatibility for this?

Answer (score 12):

Simple: you can't do this. You'll have to use some workaround.

Comment: Yes after all i'm using margin. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 12):

Well, until [CSS3 calc()](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/) is released in all major browsers, all you have to do is wrap one div with another and use some paddings-margins. OR, you can use some javascript, like counting the width of the screen and setting the width of a div accordingly.

Comment: Yes after all i'm using margin. Thanks n1313.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do this with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), if you're using a stack which supports it.  I'm only aware of Ruby, but there might well be others.

SASS is CSS-style code which generates traditional CSS, you can use variables and so on.

Comment: SASS is great...
"height: 238+9+px;" produces "height: 247px;" in the output css file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no such functionality. All you can do is:

```
width:auto;
margin-right: 10px;
```

which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve this is to construct your CSS using [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) or a similar tool and then process these files into generated CSS - you can't do it on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one uses a dynamic approach, that generates code on the fly.
For instance, in PHP, while writing the CSS part,

```
 $width = $all - 10;
 echo 'width:' . $width . 'px;';
```

Comment: Yes we can do it with PHP, but I don't handle the server side part. Moreover, I have many elements which want to be applied. Thanks ring0.