# <button> to occupy all of available width

Tags: html, css, button

It's been a long day, and I'm sure that I must be missing something here, so please go easy on me if I am!

Let's take the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="myButton">Some Text</button>
</div>
```

What I am wanting to do is to allow the `button` element to occupy all of the width afforded to it by `div#container`. Usually we can achieve this my setting the `display` property to `block` and removing any floats that might be imposed on the element (this works with other elements, such as anchors and spans).

However, by setting the CSS of `button#myButton` to the following, the button still only occupies the space of the text plus the padding I have applied:

```
button#myButton {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this might be happening. It is essential that this works in WebKit, and does not need to be cross-browser supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `width: 100%` with `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Example: http://jsbin.com/iwifon/edit

Comment: Doing that will result in the element being 100% + 20 pixels in width, surely?

Comment: Don't add padding than. The button tag does it automatically

Comment: As I suspected, when I tried your code with my markup, the button is 100% + 20px.

Comment: @BenM as @Last Rose Studios answered (albeit tersely) you can use `box-sizing: border-box` to solve that issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing

Comment: @BenM you're SOL, and have to use extra wrapper elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819908/css-width-subtraction ...or use JavaScript `*shudder*`

Comment: I think you've got an anti-admirer, @MattBall. This is the second time I've see a random downvote on one of your answers...

Answer (score 0):

input with type button or submit have box-sizing set to border-box, setting it to content-box can sometimes fix some width issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should to the trick. You need to `float:left` + `display:block` + `position:relative` to work. That makes the `width:100%` and `height:100%` work

```
button#myButton {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    /*This is new stuff below this point*/
    float:left; /*For IE*/
    position:relative;/*For the 100% to work on height and width*/
    height:100%;/*Takes all available height*/
    width:100%;/*Takes all available width*/
    border:none; /*Get rid of default border in all browsers*/
    outline:none; /*Get rid of webkit and IE borders*/
}
```